# wget download all web pages from an XML sitemap

Tags: downloads, wget, xml

I'm trying to mirror and download as static html files all of the links in an XML sitemap file.

I found the following command which is supposed to accomplish what I'm trying to achieve but it doesn't actually download anything:

> wget --quiet http://www.mydemosite.com/sitemap.xml --output-document - | egrep -o "https?://[^<]+" | wget -i -

I found this thread here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17334117/crawl-links-of-sitemap-xml-through-wget-command

So my question is, how can I mirror and download as static html files all of the links in an XML sitemap file using wget?

Thanks

Comment: The command looks OK, but doesn't work in your case. So break it down into a `wget`, an `egrep` and another `wget` command, and see why it fails.

Comment: Okay so now it works but each file name just get's created like this: index.html  index.html.1  index.html.2. Is it possible to set each downloaded html name to the page's actual title?

Comment: I would write a script for that, not attempt to do it in one long command. The script would first download all the html files as above, then post-process each to extract the title tag and rename it as `$title.html`.

Comment: Are you able to write such a script? I've posted a bounty here: https://bountify.co/wget-command-script-to-download-url-s-from-xml-file and if you can, I'd be really glad to pay you for your efforts. I really need this script and I'm not a CLI programmer.

Comment: I could, but I am sure others here are much better script writers than me.